# MySQL local - ID with auto-increment doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

So I am a beginner and I was reading a tutorial here: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4 on how to add values into my database.

This is my database:

[image]

This is the query string provided by the tutorial:

```
"INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('$first','$last','$phone','$mobile','$fax','$email','$web')";
```

Notice that the tutorial does not provide the ID on the query because it should auto-increase everytime you add a record. In my case, if I do not enter a number it does not auto-increase and in fact it does not add the record

If I manually set the number as such below, it works.

```
('2','$first','$last','$phone','$mobile','$fax','$email','$web')";
```

What I'm I doing wrong? Is it because the database is local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the tutorial put '' as the first column, whereas you are leaving it out.  I would assume you are getting an error from the MySQL engine which you are not checking.

Personally, I always use an explicit list (this protects you in case of table re-arrangement or re-factoring):

```
"INSERT INTO contacts (first, last, phone, mobile, fax, email, web)
VALUES ('$first','$last','$phone','$mobile','$fax','$email','$web')";
```

Comment: I am a javascript developer and I always try to use less code as possible. I probably should stop that with php. Thanks

Comment: @JohnyBryne This is not a PHP issue, it's a SQL issue.  You want your query to be robust in the face of expected change.  I personally would also recommend parametrized queries which aren't vulnerable to injection.  I generally advocate stored procedures, because I like my database to have a well-defined interface and do not generally allow application roles to have INSERT in a table - they get access to the database API I present, which usually will perform a variety of actions for an entity creation operation.

Comment: Literally its you are talking my chinese. Soon enough I will be able to understand that though. Thanks